# not able to set form values in <p> tag using jquery.i think error is in $("p").html("Username :"+u +"Password:"+pa); line

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
   </script>
   <script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
        `$` character is just a shortcut for `window.jQuery`.
            $("#sub").click(function()
            {
                /*fetch username password*/
                var un= $("input:text").val();

                var pa=$("input:password").val();
                //values not display
                $("p").html("**Username**:"+*un*+"**Password**:"+*pa*);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>Username
        <input type="text" name="uname">Password
        <input type="pass" name="pass">Course: java
        <input type="checkbox" name="java" value="java">Php
        <input type="checkbox" name="php" value="php">.net
        <input type="checkbox" name=".net" value=".net">javascript
        <input type="checkbox" name="javascript" value="javascript">Gender: Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Qualification:
        <select>
            <option>B.tech</option>
            <option>M.tech</option>
            <option>12</option>
            <option>10</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="sub">
        <input type="reset" value="reset">
    </form>
    <p></p>
</body>
```

Comment: i am not able to get the answer.please provide me the correct code

Comment: ohh sorry ..its type="password"..but still i am not able to hold our output

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
Password<input type="pass" name="pass" >
```

to

```
Password<input type="password" name="pass" >
```

and this

```
$("p").html("**Username**:"+*un*+"**Password**:"+*pa*);
```

to

```
$("p").html("**Username**:*"+un+"***Password**:*"+pa+"*");
```

There error in you javascript. The "*" should be in quote.

and you should comment the line

```
`$` character is just a shortcut for `window.jQuery`.
```

EDIT: yeah when submit the page will reload. so the change made from jquery will lost. add

`<form onsubmit="return false;">`

or

add `return false;` in your function.

Answer (score 0):

here there is no problem in $("p").html()

it is happening because when you clicks the submit button the after doing the action the form get reloads, so what ever changes done will be gone.

to avoid this you can make the following changes in the code.

```
<form onSubmit="javascript:return false;">
```

and in the javascript do like below

and in html better to use **password** only because that is the valid pseude . not **pass**

```
<input type="password" name="pass" >
```

Now this will work.

for more please check the complete code below

```
<!doctype html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
   </script>
   <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
       //`$` character is just a shortcut for `window.jQuery`.
        $("#sub").click(function()
                        {
        /*fetch username password*/
        var un= $("input:text").val();

        var pa=$("input:password").val();
        //values not display
         $("p").html("**Username**:"+un+"**Password**:"+pa);

    });
 });
                     </script>
                    </head>

                    <body>
                    <form onSubmit="javascript:return false;">
                    Username<input type ="text" name="uname" >
                    Password<input type="password" name="pass" >
                    Course:
                    java<input type="checkbox" name="java" value="java">
                    Php<input type="checkbox" name="php" value="php">
                    .net<input type="checkbox" name=".net" value=".net">
                    javascript<input type="checkbox" name="javascript" value="javascript">
                    Gender:
                    Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">
                    Female<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
                    Qualification:
                    <select>
                    <option>B.tech</option>
                    <option>M.tech</option>
                    <option>12</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="sub">
                    <input type="reset" value="reset">
                    </form>
                    <p></p>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
<input type="password" name="pass">
```

instead of

```
<input type="pass" name="pass">
```

and use

```
$("input:password")
```

instead of

$("input:pass")

as there is no pass pseudo supported.

in addition use input type="button" to hold the result instead of input type="submit"

Comment: yes i make the above corrections ...i get the output when user clicks on submit button  .....but the output only blinks for a second..not able to hold the output

Comment: If u need to hold the result use Input type="button" instead of type="submit".

Comment: if u want to hold the result you should use input type="button" instead of type="submit"